# Como modificar um array de objetos através de uma condição?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, ecmascript-6

Tenho o seguinte array de objetos:

```
let items = [
{
      carro: {
        title: "Gol",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
},
{
      carro: {
        title: "Gol Filho",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
      parent: 'Gol'
}]
```

Existe uma maneira simples de fazer um loop dentro desse array e verificar se algum elemento possui a string **parent** igual ao **title** de algum elemento e adicionar esse elemento dentro do objeto que satisfaz essa condição?

Exemplo:

```
let items = [
{
      carro: {
        title: "Gol",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
        },
      isVisible: true,
      children: [
          {
          carro: {
            title: "Gol Filho",
            description: "Gol quadrado",
            active: true,
            },
            isVisible: true,
            parent: 'Gol'
          }
      ]
}]
```

Comment: A lógica é a seguinte, pegue todos que não tem `parent` e pegue todos que tem `parent` e faça a junção das informações, não existe nada mágico precisa ser feito assim algum código para separar e depois unir, você fez algum código?

Comment: Você alterou a pergunta original e nela não consta recursividade de filhos com filhos dos filhos, nem a pergunta faz esse tipo de junção por isso a resposta faz o que pede e eu vou reverter a edição, se quiser por favor abra outro questionamento e seja mais claro o possivel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E algo assim, acho que resolve seu problema, onde foi separado em dois `array` de objetos os itens que tem `parent` e não e depois feito a junção com `filter`, exemplo:

```js
// matriz 
let items = [{
    carro: {
      title: "Gol",
      description: "Gol quadrado",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true,
  },
  {
    carro: {
      title: "Fusca",
      description: "Fusca 1.6",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true    
  },
  {
    carro: {
      title: "Gol Filho",
      description: "Gol quadrado",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true,
    parent: 'Gol'
  },
  {
    carro: {
      title: "Gol Filho 2",
      description: "Gol Bolinha",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true,
    parent: 'Gol'
  }
];

//criando duas variáveis para separação
let newItems = [];
let newParents = [];

//map separando os itens, poderia ser um simples for
items.map(x => {
  if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'parent')) {
    newParents.push(x);
  } else {
    newItems.push(x);
  }
});

//criando as junções se for possivel
newItems.map(x => {
  x['children'] = newParents.filter(a => a.parent == x.carro.title);
});

//mostrando os itens final
console.log(newItems);
```

---

Uma forma bem resumida:

```js
// matriz 
let items = [{
    carro: {
      title: "Gol",
      description: "Gol quadrado",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true,
  },
  {
    carro: {
      title: "Fusca",
      description: "Fusca 1.6",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true    
  },
  {
    carro: {
      title: "Gol Filho",
      description: "Gol quadrado",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true,
    parent: 'Gol'
  },
  {
    carro: {
      title: "Gol Filho 2",
      description: "Gol Bolinha",
      active: true,
    },
    isVisible: true,
    parent: 'Gol'
  }
];

const sorted = items.filter(x => {
    if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(x, 'parent')) {
      x['children'] = items.filter(a => a.parent == x.carro.title);
      return x;
    }
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: Tá perfeito, só uma dúvida, se eu precisasse adicionar sempre um filho a mais se o parent de um elemento for um filho, como eu poderia fazer? Algo recursivo que eu digo.

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta @haykou o código demonstrado acho que já faz isso! até fiz um menor também dá uma olhada!

Comment: agradeço Virgilio, é que estou tentando adicionar um children dentro de outro utilizando o parent e ele não reconhece

Answer (score 1):

### Dessa forma suporta recursividade:

```
const childrens = {};

const parentNames = items.filter(item => item.parent).map(item => {
  if(!childrens[item.parent]) {
    childrens[item.parent] = [];
  }
  childrens[item.parent].push(item);
  return item.parent;
});

const itemsWithChildrens = items.map(item => {
  if(parentNames.indexOf(item.carro.title) !== -1) {
    item.children = childrens[item.carro.title];
  }
  return !item.parent ? item : false;
}).filter(item => item);
```

#### Testei com o seguinte set:

```
let items = [
{
      carro: {
        title: "Gol",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
},
{
      carro: {
        title: "Gol Filho",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
      parent: 'Gol'
},
{
      carro: {
        title: "Outro carro",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true
},
{
      carro: {
        title: "Filho do outro carro",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
      parent: 'Outro carro'
},
{
      carro: {
        title: "Segundo neto",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
      parent: 'Gol Filho'
},
{
      carro: {
        title: "Gol Neto",
        description: "Gol quadrado",
        active: true,
      },
      isVisible: true,
      parent: 'Gol Filho'
}]
```