# Como transformar um array recursivamente?

Tags: javascript, array, recursão, objetos, ecmascript-6

Tenho o seguinte array:

```
let exemplo = [{
  alarm: {
    title: "Pai",
    id: "1"
  },
  children: [],
  parent: "",
}, {
  alarm: {
    title: "Filho",
    id: "2",
  },
  parent: "Pai",
  children: [],
}, {
  alarm: {
    title: "Neto",
    id: "3",
  },
  parent: "Pai",
  children: [],
}, {
  alarm: {
    title: "Filho 2",
    id: "4",
  },
  parent: "Pai",
  children: [],
}, {
  alarm: {
    title: "Neto 2",
    id: "5",
  },
  parent: "Filho",
  children: [],
}, {
  alarm: {
    title: "Pai 2",
    id: "6",
  },
  parent: "",
  children: [],
}, {
  alarm: {
    title: "Filho 2.2",
    id: "6",
  },
  parent: "Pai 2",
  children: [],
}];
```

Como posso transformá-lo **recursivamente** em um array de objetos com base na condição de que um **alarm** deve ser filho de um **alarm parent**?

Tentei utilizar a função abaixo mas não obtive sucesso:

```
public getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
      if (arr[i].parent === parent) {
        console.log(arr[i].alarm.parent);
        var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i]);

        if (children.length) {
          arr[i].children = children;
        }
        out.push(arr[i]);
      }
    }

    return out;
}

var nest = this.getNestedChildren(exemplo, '');
```

A saída esperada seria algo do tipo:

```
let exemplo = [
  {
    alarm: {
      title: "Pai",
      id: "1"
    },
    parent: "",
    children: [
      {
        alarm: {
          title: "Filho",
          id: "2",
        },
        parent: "Pai",
        children: [
          {
            alarm: {
              title: "Neto",
              id: "3",
            },
            parent: "Filho",
            children: [],
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Sempre obedecendo essa hierarquia, pai, filho, neto, etc, independente da quantidade de alarms.

Comment: Qual é a saída esperada?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Você usou o ```for()``` para iterar sua lista, porém está com formato inválido, acredito que queira usar o ```foreach``` pois sua estrutura está similar a do loop foreach.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como modificar um array de objetos através de uma condição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/381106/como-modificar-um-array-de-objetos-atrav%c3%a9s-de-uma-condi%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisa ser recursivo? Não vi a necessidade disso nesse exemplo, se fosse para desfazer a formatação faria sentido, mas não há porque utilizar recursividade em uma lista rasa.

Acho mais fácil você criar um array associativo (um objeto) usando o nome do alarme como chave, dessa forma você não precisa percorrer todo o array na hora de encontrar o pai.

Obs: todos os arrays em JavaScript são associativos, mesmo os enumeráveis, então isso não afeta o desemprenho.

```js
function transformar(alarmes) {
  const listaClone    = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(alarmes))
  const listaIndexada = {}
  const listaRetorno  = []

  for (const alarme of listaClone)
    listaIndexada[alarme.alarm.title] = alarme

  for (const alarme in listaIndexada) if (!listaIndexada[alarme].parent)
    listaRetorno.push(listaIndexada[alarme])
  else
    listaIndexada[listaIndexada[alarme].parent].children.push(listaIndexada[alarme])
 
  return listaRetorno
}

const exemplo = [{"alarm":{"title":"Pai","id":"1"},"children":[],"parent":""},{"alarm":{"title":"Filho","id":"2"},"parent":"Pai","children":[]},{"alarm":{"title":"Neto","id":"3"},"parent":"Pai","children":[]},{"alarm":{"title":"Filho 2","id":"4"},"parent":"Pai","children":[]},{"alarm":{"title":"Neto 2","id":"5"},"parent":"Filho","children":[]},{"alarm":{"title":"Pai 2","id":"6"},"parent":"","children":[]},{"alarm":{"title":"Filho 2.2","id":"6"},"parent":"Pai 2","children":[]}]
const listaTransformada = transformar(exemplo)

console.log(listaTransformada)
```